# JavaScript variable doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, json

So I'm creating a simple Web Page that takes data from a json file and appends a number of paragraphs equal to the number of objects in the json file array:

```
$(function () {

    function init() {
       console.log("OK");
       var dat;
       var i;
       load();
       fill();
   }

   function load()
   {
       $.get("data.json", function (data, status) {
           dat=data;
           console.log(dat);
       })
   }

   function fill()
   {
       console.log(dat);
       for(i=0; i<dat.length(); i++) $("#container").append("<p>Testing</p> <br/><br/>")
   }

    $(".front").on("load", init());
});
```

However when I run the web page the first time I try to do a console log it prints out the data however the second time, inside the fill() function it says:

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: dat is not defined"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The `dat` variable you define is local to `init()`.

Comment: Reopened because while this does have the "[return the result of an asynchronous function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)" issue, it's just one of several.

Comment: make the dat a gloable variable... Hint, outside the init() function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems:

1. `dat` is a local variable within your `init` function, so naturally code in your `load` function doesn't have access to it.
2. You're **calling** `init` and then passing its return value into `on`, not hooking up `init` as a `load` handler.
3. `$.get` is **asynchronous**, so just calling `load` and then calling `fill` won't work, `fill` will run before the GET has completed.

See comments:

```
$(function () {
   var dat; // *** Make this global to the code (it's not actually global, which is good)

   function init() {
       load(fill); // *** Pass `fill` into `load`
   }

   function load(next) // *** Accept the callback to call when ready
   {
       $.get("data.json", function (data, status) {
           dat = data;
           console.log(dat);
           next(); // *** Call it
       })
   }

   function fill()
   {
       console.log(dat);
       for(i=0; i<dat.length(); i++) $("#container").append("<p>Testing</p> <br/><br/>")
   }

    $(".front").on("load", init); // *** No () on init, you want to pass the function into `on`, not *call* the function
});
```

Some other notes:

1. You might also look into promises.
2. Unless you need `dat` for more than `fill`, consider not having the `dat` variable at all; just have `load` call `fill` with the data as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Variable dat is in scope of function init() and it doesnt exists outside that function , move variable dat outside function.

```
var dat;

function init(){

// rest of code
```

}